# Python, Key Error: 1

Tags: python, key

The goal of my code is to sort through the data and select only the Visual band or "Vis." band data. From that I eliminated all values that were upper and lower limits to clean up the graph. Finally I wanted to remove all the data that was not a part of the outbursts or decays. My filtering of Vis. band and the upper/lower limit data seems to work fine, but when I try to remove data that had a small slope it shows key error:1, I don't have enough reputation to post an image so I included a link to the plot. The plot shows data after filtering the vis band and upper/lower limits.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/LlSn1LD.png]

```
def timeplot():  
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import jdcal as jd
    import math

    #Getting input from user as to start and end dates for the data
    (miny,minm,mind) = input("Enter the start date for data in the format (yyyy,mm,dd) ex. (2000,01,01):")
    (maxy,maxm,maxd) = input("Enter the end date for data in the format (yyyy,mm,dd) ex. (2000,01,01):")

    #Calculating modified julian dates from the gregorian date input
    (x,Amin)=jd.gcal2jd(miny,minm,mind)       
    (y,Amax)=jd.gcal2jd(maxy,maxm,maxd)                  

    #Creating a table with the numbers corresponding to their month                                   
    Month = {1:'Jan', 2:'Feb', 3:'Mar', 4:'Apr', 5:'May', 6:'Jun', 7:'Jul', 8:'Aug', 9:'Sep', 10:'Oct', 11:'Nov', 12:'Dec'}                                    

    #Read in data file
    pd.set_option('html', False)
    pd.set_option('max_columns', 30)
    pd.set_option('max_rows', 2000)
    data1 = pd.read_csv("50yrdata.csv")
    data1['ulflag']=1

    #Deal with any bad columns
    data1_limit = data1.JD * 0
    ii=0
    for mag in data1.Magnitude:
        if mag[0] == '<':
            data1.ulflag[ii]=0
            data1.Magnitude[ii] = mag[1:]
            data1_limit[ii] = 1
        if mag[0] == '>':
            data1.ulflag[ii]=0
            data1.Magnitude[ii] = mag[1:]
            data1_limit[ii] = -1
        ii +=1

    #The data set has Vis, V, I, R, B, TG, TB, TR, CV bands
    #Selecting data only in the visual band with no upper or lower limits in 
    #magnitude

    #Converting Julian Date to Modified Julian Date
    data1.JD=data1.JD-2400000.5

    data1.index=data1.ulflag
    data1=data1.ix[1,['JD','Magnitude','Band']]
    data1.index=data1.Band

    tdata=data1.ix['Vis.',['JD','Magnitude']]

    #Changing all of the values from Magnitude from string to float
    tdata=tdata.astype(float)  

    #Adding on columns to make computations easier
    tdata['sflag']=0
    tdata['slope']=0.000
    tdata['aslope']=0.000
    tdata['A']=0.000
    tdata['B']=0.000

    #Finding max and min values of our MJD,
    Max=Amax
    Min=Amin

    #We split the data into N graphs where N is the number of years the data spans
    N=(int((Max-Min)/365))

    #Finding slope of the curve
    #Attempt to filter the data using
    #1. A positive slope greater than a certain threshold = outburst
    #2. A negtaive slope smaller than a certain threshold = decay 
    #3. The absolute value of the slope is smaller than a certain threshold = quiescence 

    length=len(tdata.JD)-1
    tdata.A[length]=0
    tdata.B[length]=1 

    for i in range(length):
        tdata.A[i] = tdata.Magnitude[i+1]-tdata.Magnitude[i]


    for i in range(length):
        tdata.B[i] = tdata.JD[i+1]-tdata.JD[i]


    for i in range(length+1):
        tdata.slope[i] = tdata.A[i]/tdata.B[i]


    tdata.aslope=abs(tdata.slope)


    for i in range(length):
        if tdata.aslope[i] > 1:
        tdata.sflag = 1
        if tdata.aslope[i] < 1:
        tdata.sflag = 0
        i += 1

    #filtering out all the data that has a slope less than a certain threshold
    tdata.index = tdata.sflag
    tdata=tdata.astype(float)
    tdata=tdata.ix[1,['JD','Magnitude']]

    #Plot selected data
    fig ,axs = plt.subplots(N,1)
    fig.subplots_adjust(hspace = .5)

    #Due to data set being so large, make multiple sub plots instead of one large plot
    #Magnitude axis needs to be flipped to see when the star has outbursts              
    #When setting the limits of our subplots, we extend them by a small value in
    #order to make the data easier to read. The large value being added and subtracted

    #of 365 causes the graph to cover approximately one year in data.
    axs = axs.ravel()

    for i in range(N):
        axs[i].scatter(tdata.JD, tdata.Magnitude)
        axs[i].invert_yaxis()
        axs[i].set_xlim([Min+(365*(i-1))-5, Max+5-(365*(N-i))])

        A=str(miny+i)
        B=Month[minm]
        C=str(mind)

        axs[i].set_title('A Year of data starting from ' + A + ',' + B + ',' +C)     

    #Setting title and axis, I was unable to set a shared x and y axis title
    #between the subplots, when I attempted to do this it would create another
    #plot overlapping the 4 subplots making it difficult to see the values

    fig.suptitle('SS Cyg Data', fontsize = 20)
    fig.text(0.5, 0.04, 'Modified Julian Date', ha='center', va='center')
    fig.text(0.04, 0.5, 'Magnitude', ha='center', va='center', rotation='vertical')
    plt.show()  

timeplot()
```

The full Traceback to the error is

```
    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    C:\Users\Kenny\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.2.0.1610.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, glob, loc)
    195             else:
    196                 filename = fname
    --> 197             exec compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec') in glob, loc
    198     else:
    199         def execfile(fname, *where):

    C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\499\timeplot.py in <module>()
    136     plt.show()
    137 
    --> 138 timeplot()

    C:\Users\Kenny\Dropbox\499\timeplot.py in timeplot()
    102     tdata.index = tdata.sflag
    103     tdata=tdata.astype(float)
    --> 104     tdata=tdata.ix[1,['JD','Magnitude']]
    105 
    106     #Plot selected data

    E:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
     45                 pass
     46 
     ---> 47             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
     48         else:
     49             return self._getitem_axis(key, axis=0)

    E:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.pyc in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
    251     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup):
    252         try:
    --> 253             return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
    254         except IndexingError:
    255             pass

    E:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.pyc in _getitem_lowerdim(self, tup)
    361         for i, key in enumerate(tup):
    362             if _is_label_like(key) or isinstance(key, tuple):
    --> 363                 section = self._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
    364 
    365                 # we have yielded a scalar ?

    E:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.pyc in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
    411                     return self._get_loc(key, axis=axis)
    412 
    --> 413             return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
    414 
    415     def _getitem_iterable(self, key, axis=0):

    E:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.pyc in _get_label(self, label, axis)
     59             return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis, copy=False)
     60         except Exception:
    ---> 61             return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis, copy=True)
     62 
     63     def _get_loc(self, key, axis=0):

    E:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in xs(self, key, axis, level, copy)
   2369             loc, new_index = self.index.get_loc_level(key)
   2370         else:
    -> 2371             loc = self.index.get_loc(key)
   2372 
   2373             if isinstance(loc, np.ndarray):

    E:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.pyc in get_loc(self, key)
    714         loc : int if unique index, possibly slice or mask if not
    715         """
    --> 716         return self._engine.get_loc(key)
    717 
    718     def get_value(self, series, key):

    E:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\index.pyd in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3542)()

    E:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\index.pyd in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3373)()

    E:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\index.pyd in pandas.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates (pandas\index.c:3709)()

KeyError: 1
```

Comment: And what is the *full* traceback of the exception that you get?

Comment: Sorry about that, I added the full traceback